# How to add angular directive dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs-directive

I am new for Angular JS. I have following angular directive

`angular.module('components', []).
    directive('newissueedtr', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div><textarea></textarea></div>',
        replace: true
    };`

I want to add this directive dynamically from jquery, like,

```
$('body').append('<newissueedtr></newissueedtr>')
```

Above jquery code is not working. Is it possible? Or is there any other way.

Comment: if this is happening within a angular code? you need to get hold of `$compile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which does the same u need to modify as per your needs..
http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/fBjbP/2/

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
    .directive('test', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '@'
        },
        template: '<p ng-click="add()">{{text}}</p>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.add = function () {
                var el = $compile("<test text='n'></test>")($scope);
                $element.parent().append(el);
            };
        }
    };
});

function crtl($scope) {}
```